# If $L$ is a square lower-triangular matrix, show that $LL^T$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

How may I prove the following:

> Given a matrix $L$ which is a square lower triangular matrix, prove that the following matrix is Positive Definite:
> $$LL^T$$

**In other words,** I need to prove that for each $x\neq 0$, $$x^TLL^Tx>0$$

*(Note: Is this true for every non-singular L?)*

Comment: @charlus In what way are the eigenvalues of $L$ helpful?

Comment: @charlus But what is the relationship between the eigenvalues of $L$ and the eigenvalues of $LL^T$?

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of $L^2$! Your method is the way to go then

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $L$ is supposed to be non-singular.

**Hint:** Note that $x^TLL^Tx = (L^Tx)^T(L^Tx)$.

Yes, this is true for every non-singular $L$.

Comment: That's equal to $||Lx||^2$, I know that but got stuck

Comment: @Daniel98 If $L$ is non-singular, then $\|Lx\|^2 > 0$ whenever $x \neq 0$

Comment: Thanks, last one, is $L^TL$ always PSD (or PD) - for any random matrix?

Comment: @Daniel98 Yes, $L^TL$ will always (at least) be positive semidefinite